# Task Scheduled but callback is not triggered [octobercms & laravel]

Tags: laravel, octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

I scheduled a task but it doesn't invoke given callback like following code

```php
public function registerSchedule($scheduler) {
    \Log::debug('Scheduling task');
    $scheduler->call(function(){
        \Log::debug('i\'m inside');
    })->everyMinute();
}
```

with above code it will always log "Scheduling task" but not "i'm inside" not sure why it isn't triggering callback function. There is no error thrown in logs. Can anyone please tell me in what cases this might happen? is it possible that other plugins are creating issues for callback?
So far i tried to debug and I saw that `Schedule.php` of laravel framework has a protected property called events where this callback gets stored but when dueEvents is called events property is empty. So, completely confused on what's happening here.

any help is appreciated. thank you :)

Comment: are you setting cron jobs properly : https://octobercms.com/docs/setup/installation#crontab-setup can you check this one.

Comment: Yes, It's able to reach `\Log::debug('Scheduling task');`

Comment: i mean to say did you set up cron job `* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` <- this one

Comment: `* * * * * cd /some/folder && /opt/bitnami/php/bin/php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` this is what i've added to crontab